# "Счастье есть удовольствие без раскаяния" Как правильно написать это предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Счастье есть удовольствие без раскаяния.

Comment: Признаться, не понял вопроса. Вы правильно написали. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я, о знаках препинания

Comment: В предложении правильно со знаками препинания, а после "я" в в Вашем комментарии запятая ну совсем ни к чему. ;)))

Answer (score 1):

Важен контекст: это может быть из области диетологии с психологией.

```
(Есть или не есть?) Счастье - есть, удовольствие без раскаяния!
```

Comment: Это есть единственное (по части контекста) оправдание этой безумной фразе. В точку.

Answer (score 0):

Без каких-либо знаков. Редкий случай - у нас наличествует глагол "есть" в качестве сказуемого.